# Change prototype within function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem with my javascript code. I have this prototype and I want to have it in a way where you can add 'middleware' or how you'd call it. (like in ExpressJS, `app.get('/user/:id/edit', loadUser, andRestrictToSelf, function(...)`)

```
var Server = function(...){
    ...
};
Server.prototype.log = function(data){
    console.log(data);
};
console.log(typeof(Server.prototype.log)); //function
```

So I changed it to a way where I add the functions by calling a function, so i can later implement something like `_add('fnName', loadUser, function(...))`.

```
var Server = function(...){
    ...
};
_add = function(fnName, fn){
    Server.prototype.fnName = fn;
    console.log(typeof(Server.prototype.fnName)); //always function
};
_add('log', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
console.log(typeof(Server.prototype.log)); //undefined
```

However this doesn't work. The prototype isn't changed.

I don't want to do it like in ExpressJS (you add to an instance, not the prototype) because a `Server` object will be created for every user (in combination with `socket.io`), so adding functions to objects will be more overhead than adding to the prototype whose functions are available in all instances.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but shouldn't you be using `Server.prototype[fnName]`?

Comment: OMG. :D. Thanks. What a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Server.prototype[fnName]` instead, because `Server.prototype.fnName` defines a function called `fnName` on the Server's prototype.

So in your example:

```
console.log(typeof(Server.prototype.log));   // undefined
console.log(typeof(Server.prototype.fnName)); // function
```

**Code:**

```
var Server = function(...){
  ...
};

_add = function(fnName, fn){
  Server.prototype[fnName] = fn;
  console.log(typeof(Server.prototype[fnName])); //always function
};

_add('log', function(data){
  console.log(data);
});

console.log(typeof(Server.prototype.log)); // function
```

See [this snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/VZbsX/).